# Why does Han Solo's carbonite slab have a vital signs panel on the edge?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

When the slab is pulled out of the freezing chamber, it already has a series of diagnostic panels along its edge.  One of the panels (the one nearest to Han's head) has the ability to report Han's vitals.

[image]

Considering that the carbonite freezing process at Cloud City was purely an industrial process with no medical purpose, it is somewhat strange for the final product to have such a panel.

It *seems* that the panel for the vitals was sourced from Cloud City itself, as it is Lando — not one of Vader's entourage — who reads it and reports that Han has survived.

[image]

**My questions:**

- If the freezing chamber was not specifically altered for the occasion, why would it have such a diagnostic panel?
- If it was altered for the occasion, how far in advance was the chamber altered, and was it done by Lando's staff or Vader's people?
- How is the panel even powered?  Does the freezing process install a battery, too?

Comment: When I become Emperor, I am so going to put a glass cover over the top of Han's carbonite slab and turn it into desk. Next time some regional governor or director comes whining, I will just point to Han.

Comment: @RichS : Hehe.  Shock and awe.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [Star Wars: Incredible Cross-Sections](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Incredible-Cross-Sections-Spacecraft/dp/0751370800) panel on the Carbonite chamber indicates that the (flashing) life-signs monitor panel was "*improvised*", presumably by the Ugnaughts working at Darth Vader's command in the previous scene.

As to how it's powered, note the "*power cells*" at the bottom right of the image.

[image]

Comment: Considering the same thing was apparently "improvised" [during the Clone Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Citadel), I suspect Vader had at least some input in the process

Comment: The only piece of information this answer leaves open is what would have been in the place of the life systems monitor in normal blocks of carbonite. (Arguably, possible content for a separate question, though.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - My understanding is that the answer is nothing. Under normal circumstances, you wouldn't need any of the surround, you'd just create a solid block of carbonite to trap the gas in. It can then be unfrozen at your leisure.

Comment: @Richard: Ooh, ok. Given that the "life systems monitor" is the only component marked as "improvised" in the graphic, I had assumed that the rest of the frame would normally be present, as well (and a "Carbonite flux monitor" as well as a "Gas mix ratio monitor" do sound sufficiently reasonable to verify the quality of the material, similarly as pressure tanks contain indicators that continuously allow to monitor the state of the content).

Comment: Isn't the gas primary usage for blaster weapons? Shouldn't it be a mass product then? Shouldn't a mass product be carried in much bigger compartments? This looks like a compartment for a very valuable and brittle cargo, that is only used in small amounts.

Comment: It has built-in repulsorlift? Handy!